# Can I use App Center to release my Apple Watch app (iOS/watchOS) in Swift for beta testing?

Tags: swift, watchos, watchos-3, visual-studio-app-center

I'm an experienced S/W engineer, but new to Apple and wish to distribute my app for beta testing to remote testers with Windows PCs (no Mac's).

I know other beta systems (Crashlytics) don't support watchOS, so am asking the Q before delving in to App Center.

Comment: First of all, your question is too broad to considered on topic here. Second of all, you can only use Test Flight for beta testing native iOS or watchOS apps.

Comment: So, are you saying I can't use Microsoft App Center to release my watch app to beta testers?
Can iPhone/Apple Watch users with Windows PC's receive beta versions from Test Flight?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Beta testers don't need a computer at all to install beta versions of apps on iOS/watchOS. This can be done through the Test flight app, which is an iOS app.

Comment: I am looking at Test Flight - it seems that even for Beta testing, I need an approval from Apple when all I'm trying to do at this stage is to do some very basic proof of concept stuff. 
I guess I'm not really doing Beta testing, more like Alpha testing. It all looks very complicated.
App Center appears to be a much simpler process and claims to work for iOS Beta Testing, or am I missing something important?

Comment: If you are trying to test on your dev teams' devices, you won't need Test Flight, just Xcode. You only need Test flight if you want to enable other people, whose devices are not registered under your developer ID to be able to test your app.

Comment: That's what I hoped, but I don't know how to install the app on my team's devices - they are physically remote (I'm in Sydney and they're in SFO and Kiev, Ukraine!) and they don't run Mac's but do have iPhones and Apple Watches.

Comment: @user3047912 Hey! I work on the App Center team and just added an answer below. Some of what David said sounds misleading or false to me, so tried to clarify and link some helpful documentation. Let me know if you have follow-up questions!

Answer (score 3):

In principle, this could work, yes. However, Visual Studio App Center at this time does not yet support building and signing with multiple provisioning profiles so you could not use the cloud build feature to actually build your app.

At the same time, if you build your app locally or with some other CI solution, it's absolutely possible to upload and distribute an app that contains a Watch app through App Center. The watchOS app is simply bundled with the iOS app and installation will be handled on the phone.

To do that, you need to [export your app](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev23ea8b877), sign it with an development, ad-hoc, or enterprise certificate and provisioning profile and then [upload it to App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/uploading).